# Did Sisko ever return from his tutelage with the Prophets?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, apotheosis

While re-watching Deep Space Nine and listening to the commentaries, I was struck by the fact that Sisko's "Apotheosis" was one of the goals of the entire show (IIRC, Braga really wanted this). Are there novels or other material showing what happens "after" he leaves to study with the Prophets?

Comment: Braga wasn't there yet. Must have been Berman.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, in fact he returns in time for the birth of his daughter, Rebecca Jae Sisko. He took a leave of absence, but returned to take part in defeating a massive post-Voyager [invasion of the Alpha Quadrant by the Borg](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Borg_Invasion_of_2381) as Captain of the *USS New York*. Things went downhill from there.

Read [the "Return" section of his entry on Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Benjamin_Sisko#Return_from_the_Celestial_Temple) for details of the timeline post-DS9.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the books are not canon. But yes there is a whole DS9 relaunch series of books.